# Enforce Firebase Authentication on Page

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication with Firebase UI to protect pages by requiring a user to be logged in.

In the documentation I don't see what script we need to use on the top of each page in order to determine if user is logged in. If they are not logged in I want to redirect them to the logon page.

In simple PHP, I can do the following:

```
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
}
```

I don't see what is needed to be included in the Firebase JS authentication (and/or using Firebase UI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript you can detect whether the user is signed in with:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

See the [Firebase documentation on determining what user is signed in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: bingo. now comparing it with the php version I see that I need to add a redirect to the login page inside of the else clause. thank you.